# How to access Intel Random Number generator RdRand in C++?

Tags: c++, intel, rdrand

Normally, I use the following lines to generate pseudo-random numbers in C++ code:

```
srand(time(0));
int x = rand() % 100; // 0 ~ 99
```

But since Intel has implemented random generator hardware in their new processors,  I want to take advantage of the true 'randomness' from thermal fluctuations. I have searched Intel C++ compiler documents but didn't find a definitive guide on the **RdRand** API.

I looked at this post:
[True random numbers with C++11 and RDRAND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616960/true-random-numbers-with-c11-and-rdrand)

But it didn't show explicitly how to call this function in C++.

So my question is what compiler or library supports **RdRand** now and what's the C++ code template to call it.

Comment: Make sure you only call srand once per program.

Comment: I think `srand(time(0))` can be called multiple times to reseed the random number sequence.

Comment: That's true. Sorry I didn't make my comment clear enough. I've seen examples of calling srand before every call to rand, so I thought that may be what you are doing here.